# Can I still change my Firebase-database url/name after update?

Tags: firebase

When i create a new project, i get the random name for my database.

Question is can i use a **custom url** or i can only use the name assigned by **firebase** in this new update ?

When i import a project it keeps the custom url intact but when i create the new database i am not getting any options for custom URL.

For example, I have have my database on the url:

project-123456789.firebaseio.com

Is it possible to change the 'project-123456789' piece of the url in the new update? If yes, how?

Answer (score 1):

create a new project on the legacy console and then import to new google console